# How to return the change to the sender?

Tags: solidity, web3j

In this answer, @pabloruiz55 provides the following code for sending ether.

SmartContract.sol

```
function transferToOwner() payable returns (bool) {
    //Sender should forward at least 1 ether.
    require(msg.value > 1 ether);
    uint amountToSend = 1 ether;
    uint change = msg.value - amountToSend; // Do something with the change. Return it to sender, maybe?
    // If you don't do anything with the change, it will be stuck on this contract
    owner.transfer(1 ether);
    return true;
}
```

What would be the code for?

```
// Do something with the change. Return it to sender, maybe?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the amount of `change` and transfer it to the msg.sender. The code to return the Ether to the sender is (just add this line):

`msg.sender.transfer(change)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, it helps but what looks strange about the code? What edits would you propose?

Comment: I just think it is better to ask the user to send the right amount from the beginning. But there is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: You did. +1. [Please consider answering this follow up related question.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/48316/31868) https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/48316/31868