# How does one require a specific amount of ether to execute a contract?

Tags: solidity, remix

The following code requires 1 ether but works by accepting greater amounts and returns the change. How could one modify this code to require exactly one ether be paid in the first place and thereby eliminate the need to calculate change?

SmartContract.sol

```
function transferToOwner() payable returns (bool) {
    //Sender should forward at least 1 ether.
    require(msg.value > 1 ether);
    uint amountToSend = 1 ether;
    uint change = msg.value - amountToSend;
    msg.sender.transfer(change); // return change to sender
    owner.transfer(1 ether);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do:

```
function transferToOwner() payable returns (bool) {
    require(msg.value == 1 ether,"Amount should be equal to 1 Ether");
    owner.transfer(1 ether);
    return true;
}
```

If the person tries sending less or more than 1 ether the transaction will not be executed. They will also receive a message.

Note that the user will receive a warning before the transaction is executed so that they do not lose any ether.

Hope this help.

UPDATE based on OP comments:

You can set the owner in many ways, the easiest way is in the constructor:

```
Contract MyContract{

    address public owner;
    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    } 

    function transferToOwner() payable returns (bool) {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether,"Amount should be equal to 1 Ether");
        owner.transfer(1 ether);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Like this, `owner` is who deployed the contract.

Hope this help.

Comment: How is the `owner` defined in this code?

Comment: This owner address variable was already in your example, I assumed you defined it. If not, owner is normally who deployed the contract. So you can assign this in the constructor. Take a look at the answer, I updated it.